# Is there an alternative in Flex to do want SuspendLayout and ResumeLayout do in windows Forms?

Tags: apache-flex

That is to Temporarily suspend the layout logic for a control in Flex so it doesn't loose CPU time when trying to render the new data that i am updating or creating until i finish the updates in the controls that need to

Thanks

Comment: That all depends on what you're trying to update, how it's being done, if you're using binding, using proper flex component lifecycles, etc etc

Comment: can you show me some examples on how to do it please?

Comment: I'm not here to do work for you.  You do your research, you figure out what you're trying to do and if you have a specific question along the way that you can't find online, you ask here.

Comment: @J_A_X, I don't think that's really fare in this case.  The original question is pretty specific and straightforward IMO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem that `SuspendLayout` and `ResumeLayout` in WinForms is solved in Flex via `invalidateProperties` and `commitProperties`.  Both sets of methods are meant to allow lots of property updates while delaying the corresponding UI updates until the property updates are all done.

Basically, instead of doing anything in property setters, just have them update the backing store and a `xxxChanged` flag and call `invalidateProperties()`.  Then override `commitProperties`, remember to call `super.commitPropeties()`, and have a lot of `if (xxxChanged) { ...; xxxChanged = false; }` statements that do the actual propagation of properties to UI.

There's a good and large article on the subject here:  http://www.billdwhite.com/wordpress/?p=21